# Logo in the header loads and then disappears on the mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, responsive

The logo in the header loads and then disappears on the mobile view. Reloading the page causes it to appear and then disappear.  This only happens when using a phone, and I can't seem to replicate this behavior on a desktop screen. I'm trying to track down what may be causing this behavior?
http://www.georgefoxconference.com

Comment: This is likely to do with a missing `.circle.first` element although I have been unable to replicate the problem in Chrome's responsive mode. If you provide more information about what the phone model is it might help get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: You can reproduce the problem with chrome's mobile viewport emulation using a screen-resolution of `375x812` (e.g. `iPhone X`).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of css rules that apply only on a certain viewport width through media-queries (in style.css).

But no matter how you change your external css, the actual img-tag `div.navbar-brand > a > img` has set an inline-style attribute `display: none;` which, on a wider viewport is set to `display: inline;`. It changes on small viewports after the pageload finished.

I assume *the img's style attribute is changed via javascript*.

You can reproduce this behaviour with chrome's mobile emulation using a screen-resolution of `375x812` (e.g. `iPhone X`).

Comment: Thank you! As it turns out, there was a bit of javascript that was adding css attributes to the inline style, including the inline img class to display:none on smaller viewports.